# Binding custom layers in scapy

Tags: python-2.7, binding, layer, scapy, ieee

I have a python script which assembles and sends AVB (IEEE) packets into a network.
The packets will be captured by wireshark.
With an other python script I iterate through the capture file.
But I can't access a few parameters in a few layers because scapy doesn't know them. 
So I have to add those layers to scapy.

Here's the packet in wireshark:
[image]

I added the following code to the file "python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py"

```
class ieee(Packet):
  name = "IEEE 1722 Packet"
  fields_desc=[ XByteField("subtype", 0x00),
                XByteField("svfield", 0x81),
                XByteField("verfield", 0x81)]

bind_layers(Dot1Q, ieee1722, type=0x22f0)
```

When I execute the python script which should grab the parameters in the new layer (IEEE 1722 Protocol), the following error occurs:
"IndexError: Layer [ieee1722] not found"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the solution by editing the type value:

```
  bind_layers(Dot1Q, ieee1722, type=0x88f7) ---> works
```

Dot1Q is the layer above the created ieee1722 layer (see wireshark).
You can see the type value by clicking at the layer of a packet in wireshark.

Comment: `type` should be the name of a field.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, maybe they didn't have the doc page but they have it now:
"Adding new protocols"
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html